# Using multiple EditText by looping and get the input into double value

Tags: android

I want to take input by looping edit text then convert the value to double value and calculate with the values in android studio.

```
for (i=0;i<length;i++){
                    EditText editText = new EditText(CurrentActivity.this);
                    editText.setId(i+1);
                    editText.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                    editText.setHint("GPA "+(i+1));
                    editText.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                    params.setMargins(0, 2, 2, 2);
                    editText.setLayoutParams(params);
                    editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
                    lnrDynamicEditTextHolder.addView(editText);

                } // How I will take double value from here to calculation
```

//Error seems here...

```
    for (l=0;l<length;l++){
mEditText[i] = (EditText)findViewById(i) ;
                    z = mEditText.getText().toString();

Shubho[i] = Double.parseDouble(z); //when i put this app be stopped.
                }
```

Error on Run...

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.example.shubho.schoolcollegegpa, PID: 6522
              java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: ""
                  at java.lang.StringToReal.invalidReal(StringToReal.java:63)
                  at java.lang.StringToReal.parseDouble(StringToReal.java:267)
                  at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:301)
                  at com.example.shubho.schoolcollegegpa.CurrentActivity$1.onClick(CurrentActivity.java:100)
                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5272)
                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21562)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5765)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679)
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 6522 SIG: 9
Application terminated.
```

Comment: Please share more details, so that i can understand what you want to do ?

Comment: You should also attempt things yourself first, then use a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

You can get the value from EditText like String and convert to double like this:

`double value = Double.parseDouble(editText.getText().toString())`

then you can use `value` to make your calculation.

Comment: Add your code to your question. And I can improve my answer.

Comment: I had added my code's part. I am new here to asking. maybe i am fail to ask well. but I have tried.